# Rebuilding bootable RAID1 array

Tags: linux, raid, boot, software-raid, mdadm

I have a home server, running Linux, which has a 2-disk software RAID1 device mounted on `/`. I recently had to replace one of the disks, so I removed the faulty one, put in a new one and added it to the array.

Since the RAID device is the root filesystem, is that all I need to do, or do I need to restore any special bootable stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after the raid is done rebuilding, you might have to install grub to the second drive
usually `grub-install` or in grub console `root (hdX,Y); setup (hdX)` are enough

Comment: Thanks. I had to research a bit on how to find the X and Y, but that's ok since I now understand more about the MBR and how Grub works.